# Trouble connecting Kinect V1 with ROS Noetic

Tags: kinect, ubuntu, ros-noetic, libfreenect

I am currently attempting to connect the Kinect V1 RGB-D camera with ROS Noetic. So far I have used the following approaches according to the instructions given in the link [https://aibegins.net/2020/11/22/give-your-next-robot-3d-vision-kinect-v1-with-ros-noetic/]

1. Installed Libfreenect and tested the camera and micro phone both are working #
2. Created a ros workspace
3. Cloned rgbd_launch and freenect_stack in the src folder
4. ran the catkin_make command in the workspace folder
5. ran the command: roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch depth_registration:=true

Now I am stuck with step 5 where I am receiving the warnings as shown in the image attached below. This causes the RGB and Depth stream flush to stop as shown in the image below after the warnings which says [Stopping device RGB and depth stream flush ]. I then have to hit Ctrl C to kill the operation. What I have assumed is after entering the launch command the compilation would be complete and then I must type rviz in the next command to activate rviz[image] and select the depth_image as shown in the next image. Being a beginner to ROS I am sure I had made a simple mistake somewhere. Could someone please clarify where have I missed a step?. Looking forward.[image: Error]

Comment: Hi, Please edit your question to clarify "This causes the RGB and Depth stream flush to stop. " those warnings don't look like they will stop the operations of the node. What do you expect to see and what are you seeing instead are valuable pieces of information.